# Sharepoint 2013 document library

Tags: sharepoint-server

Dears,

I need your kind support to do the following scenario:

One of our departments has requested to create a document library and each document in this list will have multiple approvers (will be added to people picker) and each approver should provide his feedback (Approved/Rejected) and also his comments(which may include documents) on that document.

What is the solution I can follow to do this?

Note: we have some issue with sharepoint workflow platform so we cannot use it at this time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable content approval for submitted items on that document library.

Please refer below reference which shows complete steps along with an example to approve/reject items in document library.

[Approve documents without workflow](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-approve-documents-without-building-a-workflow/)

Comment: thank you for your reply, but I've tried this solution but it doesn't fit the required scenario so I need another solution than Content Approval.

Comment: @AhmedAltaweel At what scenario does it fail?

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve it from one of below approaches.

1. Workflow
2. Event Receiver
3. Custom Code

I will suggest you, if workflow is not possible for you then try event receiver.